# pandas read_excel causes the frozen app using cx_freeze to stop

Tags: python, pandas, cx-freeze

I am developing a small tool for data processing and am using cx_freeze 6.9 to get this tool to an executable. The problem is that the frozen app always comes to a halt when it reaches a function using pandas.read_excel().
Here is an example code to reproduce my problem. It doesn't give any error and the script itself works normally from the compiler but doesn't work after frozen. When I debugged my original code I figured out it is the read_excel function

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, filedialog
import pandas as pd
import os


class Processing:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def filter_data(self):
        output = self.df.iloc[1]
        return output


class Run:
    def __init__(self, input_path, output_path):
        self.input_path = input_path
        self.output_path = output_path

    def read_data(self):
        metadata = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(
            self.input_path, 'Hilfstabelle_Klarnamen.xlsx'), sheet_name=None)
        return metadata

    def data_gen(self):
        dfs = self.read_data()
        for key in dfs:
            process = Processing(dfs[key])
            resultant = process.filter_data()
            resultant.to_csv(os.path.join(
                self.output_path, f'dummy_{key}.csv'), sep=';')


class Tool_GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('350x200')
        self.INPUT_PATH = None
        self.OUTPUT_PATH = None
        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_content.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.input_button = ttk.Button(
            self.frame_content, text='Browse input...',
            command=self.browse_input)
        self.input_button.pack()
        self.output_button = ttk.Button(
            self.frame_content, text='Browse output...',
            command=self.browse_output)
        self.output_button.pack()
        self.run_button = ttk.Button(
            self.frame_content, text='Run')
        self.run_button.pack()

    def browse_input(self):
        """Callback for the browse button for the input path (folder).
        """
        self.INPUT_PATH = filedialog.askdirectory()

    def browse_output(self):
        """Callback for the browse button to get the output path (folder).
        """
        self.OUTPTUT_PATH = filedialog.askdirectory()

    def run_callback(self):
        run = Run(input_path=self.INPUT_PATH,
                  output_path=self.OUTPTUT_PATH)
        run.data_gen()


def main():
    gui = Tool_GUI()
    gui.run_button.config(command=gui.run_callback)
    gui.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Does anyone have a clue why this happens?